# Plot a function with a discrete part

Tags: plotting

I would like to plot a function like this one:

```
f[x_] = Piecewise[{{x, x ∈ Integers && x > 0}, {1/2, x < 0}}, Indeterminate]

DiscretePlot[f[x], {x, -2, 2}] 

Plot[f[x], {x, -2, 2}]
```

When I use `DiscretePlot` I get only the first part and when I use `Plot` I get only the part with `y = 1/2`. How can I solve this?

Comment: it works for me. can you provide your code.

Comment: fro the DiscretePlot try AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, for Plot, it is ok because Plot dose not do Discrete Plot

Comment: When I add AxesOrigin -> {0, 0} to DiscretePlot, there are points (x, 1/2) where x is Integer, still it's not continuous

Comment: DiscretePlot does not do continuous plotting. continuous  can be done with Plot. but remember, your function when x>0 is not continues it is  discrete (f[0.5] return Indeterminate)

Comment: I know, and it is the most important for me, because I need to create a function in part discrete and in part continuous. But I have problem with plot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Show[Plot[f[x], {x, -2, 0}], 
 DiscretePlot[f[x], {x, 0, 2}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}], 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]